# Sort related table inside of the loop to build js array from php

Tags: php, laravel

Quick question, I have Model that related to different model (one to many).

I'm building method that should return js array with related table included to array.

But I need to sort a bit `warrant_grants`, I need to return `$warrant_grants->where('status', active)`. So My `->where()` doesn't work this way:

```
public function warrants($company_id){
    $company = auth()->user()->companies()->findOrFail($company_id);
    $warrants = $company->warrants;
    foreach($warrants as $warrant) {
       //this doesn't work
       $warrant->warrantGrants->where('status', 'active');
    }
    $warrants = $warrants->toArray();
    return array_splice($warrants, 0);
}
```

Relationship:

```
public function warrantGrants()
{
    return $this->hasMany(WarrantGrant::class);
}
```

Need this little help, bc it returns me data with any status, I need only 'active'

Comment: Please don't post images of code, edit your question and add your code there. Read here for more details [Why not upload images of code when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: didn't know ppl don't like screenshots :) removed

Comment: Company::find(1)->warrantGrants()->where(['status' => 'active'])

Comment: You should add some details, like your relationships, the question could be quick but the answer is not with the code given.

Comment: added relationship method.

Comment: What is warrants ? Mention your table structure or relationship that in which model you have definite what relationship. There is no clearity between warrants and warrant_grants

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$company = App\Company::whereHas('warrants.warrantGrants', function ($query) {
     $query->where('status', '=', 'active');
})->get();
```

Comment: doesn't work this way :( I'm confused bc  that, supposed to work with my and yours either ways. I added the whole method.

Comment: What it returns?

Comment: share your code for defined relationship in question.

Comment: relationship added. It returns all `warrantGrants`, but I need only that have status 'active'